# How can i execute awk script with find command on multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, awk

This command is working fine for me for single file

```
awk -f test.awk template.yml file.yml > tmp && mv tmp file.yml
```

The fins command i have find all files i want

```
find . -wholename "*vars/*.yml"
```

I am not sure how can i execute above awk command on all files so that they can get replaced in place. I have old version of awk 3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU `awk` has inplace modification option, if you have GNU `awk`:

```
find . -wholename "*vars/*.yml" -exec awk -i inplace -f test.awk {} +
```

Otherwise, you need to handle the files one at a time:

```
find . -wholename "*vars/*.yml" -exec \
     bash -c 'awk -f test.awk "$1" >"$1".tmp && mv "$1".tmp "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: I mentioned before as well that i have old version of awk, which don't have inplace modification

Comment: Thanks , i also have to give extra file template.yml to awk for every file. so file.yml will get replaced by find but template.yml will stay there for

Comment: @Karl Hmm.. the second solution should solve your problem. Just add `template.yml` after the `test.awk`

Comment: @sjsam thanks it worked, i thought $1 might not get affected by that